# data.frame: find last index of a value in each row

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a `data.frame` like

```
  a b c d
1 1 0 0 1
2 1 1 0 0
3 0 1 0 0
4 1 0 1 0
5 1 0 0 0
```

Which I generated using

```
df<- data.frame(a=sample(0:1,5,replace=T),b=sample(0:1,5,replace=T),c=sample(0:1,5,replace=T),d=sample(0:1,5,replace=T))
```

How can I get the result as `4, 2, 2, 3, 1` if I pass 1 to that function depicting to find the last index of 1 in each row.

Comment: yes @akrun. i was using codebunk which was not allowing me to copy.

Comment: Suppose you have a row with only 0's what will be the index for that row?

Comment: @akrun -1 should be fine. or maybe 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach would be:

```
apply(df, 1, function(x) max(which(x == 1)))
```

If you wanted to be flexible about which element you're checking for and handle cases where the value is missing from a row:

```
max.row <- function(df, val) unname(apply(df, 1, function(x) tail(c(NA, which(x == val)), 1)))
max.row(df, 0)
# [1] 3 4 4 4
max.row(df, 1)
# [1] 4 2 2 3
max.row(df, 2)
# [1] NA NA NA NA
```

Answer (score 4):

you can try `max.col` which is a little bit faster than `apply`

```
max.col(df, "last")
# [1] 2 4 4 2 4
```

*Data*

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(a=sample(0:1,5,replace=T),b=sample(0:1,5,replace=T),c=sample(0:1,5,replace=T),d=sample(0:1,5,replace=T))
```

Comment: Set a seed and generate the `df` again, otherwise the results you are showing won't match with anybody else. +1 however

Answer (score 4):

Another option is using `pmax`.  We multiply the `col(df)` by 'df' and get the `max` value by row.

```
  do.call(pmax,col(df)*df)
  #[1] 4 2 2 3 1
```

`col(df)` is a convenient function to get the column index of the dataset.

```
  col(df)
  #     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
  #[1,]    1    2    3    4
  #[2,]    1    2    3    4
  #[3,]    1    2    3    4
  #[4,]    1    2    3    4
  #[5,]    1    2    3    4
```

By doing the multiplication of 'df' with the `col(df)` of equal dimension, the '0' values will remain 0 while the places that are '1' will be replaced by the column index, i.e.

```
 col(df)*df
 #  a b c d
 #1 1 0 0 4
 #2 1 2 0 0
 #3 0 2 0 0
 #4 1 0 3 0
 #5 1 0 0 0
```

Now, we can get the `max` value per each row by `do.call(pmax)`

Answer (score 0):

Seeing all the possible solutions and one from my side, here are the times taken by each replicated 10,000 times

```
apply(df,1,function(x){tail(which(x==1),1)})
user  system elapsed
2.978  0.010  2.988


apply(df*col(df),1,function(x){max(x)})
user  system elapsed
8.217  0.026  8.245



apply(df, 1, function(x) max(which(x == 1)))
user  system elapsed
1.621  0.005  1.627


max.col(df, "last")
user  system elapsed
1.348  0.004  1.352
```

Though @Mamoun Benghezal's answer is the most efficient, it doesn't solve my purpose of being flexible. The accepted answer does.